# How to make two list have the same items (but their own sequence)

Tags: c#, list

I have two list object A and B like this:

```
A=[
  {item:1, value:"ex1"},
  {item:2, value:"ex1"},
  {item:3, value:"ex1"},
  {item:4, value:"ex1"}]

B=[{item:1, value:"ex2"},
   {item:4, value:"ex2"},
   {item:2, value:"ex3"},
   {item:5, value:"ex3"}]
```

How can i do to make B to have same items/values like A and still keep its own sequence for items it already has?

I want B to remove item 5 because A don't have it, and add in item 3 to the end.

I don't want to clone A, I want to modify B to become like A.

**What I want is:**

- Remove items in B when A don't have them: item5
- Update items in B when both A and B have them: item1, item2, item4
- Add non-existing items to end of B when A have them: item3

So, the result should be like this:

```
B = [ {item:1, value:"ex1"},
      {item:4, value:"ex1"},
      {item:2, value:"ex1"},
      {item:3, value:"ex1"} ]
```

Mycode: (This is what i have now)

```
foreach (myClass itm in A)
{
     foreach (myClass fd in B)
     {
          if (itm.item == fd.item)
          {
              fd.value = itm.value;
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: It sounds like what you want is just a copy of `A`. Why does `B` matter?

Comment: @Marathon55 but i want B to remain its sequence and just update the value.

Comment: This is not very clear. Do you want to make a copy of `A` and clone all its elements, or do you want to modify `B` so that it looks like `A`. please add more detail to your question

Comment: @MichaelRandall sorry for that. I updated the question.Hope its clear now

Comment: show us your code

Comment: @Agent_Orange updated. Currently i only know how to update the value. I cant figure out  the part of add and remove

Comment: "I don't want to clone A, I want to modify B to become like A.". If you are required to use List<T> then the answer is straightforward. See the proposed answer below.

Comment: Do not remove anything. Just loop through `A` and if you find a match in `B`, update and add it to a new list. After you are done, loop through `A` again and if you do not find a match in `B`, add it to the end of the new list you created before. Do not worry about performance unless you need to and then you can do it differently.

Comment: @Bahrom the answer provided by Prasanth Louis has some errors... see my comment/ans

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method that merges the lists by iterating over the keys and checking for existence.

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public void MergeInto<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> rhs, Dictionary<TKey,TValue> lhs)
    {
        foreach (var key in rhs.Keys.Union(lhs.Keys).Distinct().ToList())
        {
            if (!rhs.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                lhs.Remove(key);
                continue;
            }
            if (!lhs.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                lhs.Add(key, rhs[key]);
                continue;
            }
            lhs[key] = rhs[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Test program:

```
public class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<int,string> A = new Dictionary<int,string>
    {
        { 1,"ex1" },
        { 2,"EX2" },
        { 3,"ex3" },
    };

    public static Dictionary<int,string> B = new Dictionary<int,string>
    {
        { 1,"ex1" },
        { 2,"ex2" },
        { 4,"ex4" }
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        A.MergeInto(B);

        foreach (var entry in B )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1=ex1
2=EX2
3=ex3
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9pK8P2)

Comment: good, but OP asked about `List<T>` not `Dictionary<int,string>`. If there is no reason to use `List`, this could be a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

### Without preserving order

If all you want to do is keep the instance of B, but make it so all its elements match A, you can just do this:

```
B.Clear();
B.AddRange(A);
```

### Preserving order

If you want to preserve order, you can still use the solution above, but you will need to sort the list that is passed to `AddRange()`. This is only a little more work.

First, create a lookup table which tells you the order that that Item values originally appeared in. A generic c# `Dictionary` uses a hash table for the keys, so this is going to end up being more efficient than scanning the List repeatedly. Note that we pass `B.Count` to the constructor so that it only needs to allocate space once rather than repeatedly as it grows.

```
var orderBy = new Dictionary<int,int>(B.Count);
for (int i=0; i<B.Count; i++) orderBy.Add(B[i].Item, i);
```

Now we use our solution, sorting the input list:

```
B.Clear();
B.AddRange
(
    A.OrderBy( item => orderBy.GetValueOrFallback(item.Item, int.MaxValue) )
);
```

`GetValueOrFallback` is a simple extension method on `Dictionary<,>` that makes it simpler to deal with keys that may or may not exist. You pass in the key you want, plus a value to return if the key is not found. In our case we pass `int.MaxValue` so that new items will be appended to the end.

```
static public TValue GetValueOrFallback<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> This, TKey keyToFind, TValue fallbackValue)
{
    TValue result;
    return This.TryGetValue(keyToFind, out result) ? result : fallbackValue;
}
```

### Example

Put it all together with a test program:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Item { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return Item.ToString() + "," + Value; }
}

static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public TValue ValueOrFallback<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> This, TKey keyToFind, TValue fallbackValue)
    {
        TValue result;
        return This.TryGetValue(keyToFind, out result) ? result : fallbackValue;
    }

    static public void MergeInto(this List<MyClass> mergeFrom, List<MyClass> mergeInto)
    {
        var orderBy = new Dictionary<int,int>(mergeFrom.Count);
        for (int i=0; i<mergeInto.Count; i++) orderBy.Add(mergeInto[i].Item, i);
        mergeInto.Clear();
        mergeInto.AddRange
        (
            mergeFrom.OrderBy( item => orderBy.ValueOrFallback(item.Item, int.MaxValue) )
        );
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static List<MyClass> A = new List<MyClass>
    {
            new MyClass { Item = 2,Value = "EX2" },
            new MyClass { Item = 3,Value = "ex3" },
            new MyClass { Item = 1,Value = "ex1" }
    };
    public static List<MyClass> B = new List<MyClass>
    {
            new MyClass { Item = 1,Value = "ex1" },
            new MyClass { Item = 2,Value = "ex2" },
            new MyClass { Item = 4,Value = "ex3" },
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        A.MergeInto(B);
        foreach (var b in B) Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1,ex1
2,EX2
3,ex3
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QHBINR)

Comment: No, i don't think he want this. It is clearly stated that he want to keep the sequence of existing items in B. The `Clear` and `AddRange` will override it as a clone of A

Comment: Edited to preserve sequence/order.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you specify in the question. I tested it and it works:

```
class myClass
{
    public int item;
    public string value;
    //ctor:
    public myClass(int item, string value) { this.item = item; this.value = value; }
}

static void updateList()
{
    var listA = new List<myClass> { new myClass(1, "A1"), new myClass(2, "A2"), new myClass(3, "A3"), new myClass(4, "A4") };
    var listB = new List<myClass> { new myClass(1, "B1"), new myClass(4, "B4"), new myClass(2, "B2"), new myClass(5, "B5") };

    for (int i = 0; i < listB.Count; i++) //use index to be able to use RemoveAt which is faster
    {
        var b = listB[i];
        var j = listA.FindIndex(x => x.item == b.item);

        if (j >= 0) //A has this item, update its value
        {
            var v = listA[j].value;
            if (b.value != v) b.value = v;
        }
        else //A does not have this item
        {
            listB.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    foreach (var a in listA)
    {
        //if (!listB.Contains(a)) listB.Add(a);
        if (!listB.Any(b => b.item == a.item)) listB.Add(a);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something similar to this:

```
        var listA = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5 };
        var listB = new List<int> { 1, 4, 3 };

        //Removes items in B that aren't in A.
        //This will remove 4, leaving the sequence of B as 1,3
        listB.RemoveAll(x => !listA.Contains(x));

        //Gets items in A that aren't in B
        //This will return the number 5
        var items = listA.Where(y => !listB.Any(x => x == y));

        //Add the items in A that aren't in B to the end of the list
        //This adds 5 to the end of the list
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            listB.Add(item);
        }

        //List B should be 1,3,5
        Console.WriteLine(listB);
```

Comment: Estimated time for processing two 1M arrays is about 2 hours. That is approximately two hours longer than one should reasonably expect.

Comment: Questioner never asked for large data sets. This is me just writing sudo code to answer his question. As far as I know he has 4 items in his question. He can update his question if he wants to

Comment: No one would like to read a question with two million rows. The example has to be ultra small. It is inevitable and as such, it says nothing about the size of the problem. You can not assume from this, that the real problem is always ultra small. And 1M items is not large, it is ordinary problem size you meet everywhere.

Comment: This answer is fine. The OP never asked for the most performant algorithm. Why worry about problems if they are not a problem yet.

Comment: I don't see anything especial stipulated in the question. So the solution must be straightforward, I think, like in this answer.

Comment: This answer has some errors! it doesn't **Update** same keys. Also the code `var items = listA.Where(y => !listB.Any(x => x == y))` is wrong here as its x and y's are of type myClass and `==` may not check them properly by the key and/or value!